# WLAN adaptor with driver support for dual-channel use

Tags: wifi, wlan

I'm looking for WLAN (WiFi) chipsets or adaptors that support simultaneous dual-channel use and where this capability is exposed via the current Linux drivers. The primary use-case is to support simultaneous operation as a station on one channel and as an access-point on a different channel. This could be either:

- Simultaneous operation on two channels in the same band (2.4GHz or 5GHz) - much preferred;
- Simultaneous operation as a station on a channel in one band and an AP on a channel in the other band.

This would be a device where `iw list` would not have the restriction `#channels <= 1` under "valid interface combinations".

For a bonus, mesh should be supported.

A sort of similar question ([full-featured WLAN USB adaptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58772/30316)) was asked 5 years ago but the world has moved on since then.

Comment: This sounds to me like a [hardware recommendation request](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that pointer, although looking at the traffic there it tends to be rather higher level in nature than what I am looking for. But if I can find a product then I just need to work out what chips it uses.

Answer (score 1):

The capability is exposed by allowing you to assign multiple network interfaces with `iw dev ... add ..` just like for the 1-channel case, and then making using different channels work.

For reference, I have a `Asus PCE-AC55BT B1` PCEe x1 card, with `Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)` chipset. (The Bluetooth function is exposed via an USB device).

Combinations show up under `iw list` as:

```
valid interface combinations:
  * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
  total <= 3, #channels <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We have recently started using the [QCA9377 Chipset](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/qca9377) which has these capabilities. Not had much of a chance to test out performance yet.